# Split a sentence into multiple sentences using key strings

Tags: python, text-processing, regex

I am using the python language for natural language processing tasks and I am running into the following problem: I have a vector of sentences of the type pandas.core.series.Series and I want to split each sentence (one column) into four separate sentences (four columns) taking as reference to break the main sentence four key strings.

The sentences have the following general structure:

**Problem:** USUÁRIO INFORMA QUE HÁ UMA NF REJEITADA NO SISTEMA.  **Cause:** Atualmente no SAP há uma tratativa para converter a informação de "UF" quando o Cliente é do exterior, porém essa tratativa ainda não existe para Transportadores. Desse modo, a nota fiscal é rejeitada por ter um valor incompatível nesta tag no XML.  **Solution:** Foi necessário acionar a equipe do Triangulus para realização de ação paliativa ajustando o conteúdo da tag cidada, permitindo o reenvio e autorização da nota fiscal. Reforçamos que seria necessária uma Melhoria para correção definitiva do problema.  **User:** Carlos Dontel.  BUGFIX: 10745625

The strings in bold face are the keys that i want to use split my sentences, i.e., **Problem:**, **Cause:**, **Solution:** and **User:**.

Is it possible to accomplish that using python?

Answer (score 1):

Iterate word-by-word and append newlines before each keyword if you see one.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
word_list=['Problem:','Cause:',
           'Solution:','User:']
with open(sys.argv[1]) as f:
    for line in f:
       for word in line.strip().split():
           if word in word_list:
               print("\n"+word,end=" ")
           else:
               print(word,end=" ")
```